# Why does my jenkins script seem to 'forget origin' even though it pull code from it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

below is my script. idea is to create projects based off of a template project so the developer would not need to do repeat this work every time a new project comes along... the template project will have all necessary scripts to run CI, release automatically, and deploy automatically...

```
  node {
    try {
        stage('Clean Up') {
            deleteDir()

            stage('Verify New Github Repo Exists') {
                sh 'git ls-remote git@github.com:account/${githubProject}.git' // check if repo exist

                stage('Clone Github Repo') {
                    // clone into directory and cd
                    sh 'git clone git@github.com:account/${githubProject}.git .'
                    sh 'git remote -v'
                    sh 'ls -lash'

                    stage('Merge Template Into Project') {
                        // add the template into the project
                        sh 'git remote add template git@github.com:account/${appType}-jenkins-ci-template.git'
                        sh 'git remote -v' // this shows both origin and template repos
                        sh 'git fetch --all'
                        sh 'git merge template/master' // able to merge origin's master with template's
                        sh 'ls -lash'
                        sh 'git log --graph --abbrev-commit --max-count=10'                        
                        sh 'git push -u origin master' // when the code get here, it fails to push, ends up with ERROR: Repository not found.

                        // do the work to replace all __APP_NAME__ with the actual app name/service
                        // commit and push to master
                        stage('Configure Project Properties') {
                            // clone and copy property files from template project
                            // do the work to replace all __APP_NAME__ with the actual app name/service
                            // commit and push to master
                            stage('Wrap Up') {
                                // creating jenkins jobs will continue to be manual
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        //notifyFailure(e, "Script failure!")
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to merge to branches without a common ancestor is problematic.  Your issue here is not a Jenkins issue it's a git issue.

Comment: good point.. the new project has no content at all; then i merge the template. i'll try out a force push...

Comment: @RichDuncan thanks for the tip. it was indeed permission issue. my jenkins did not have write permission...